# operations with bytes in c

Tags: c, sockets, byte

I am currently working on something involving sockets in C and I am facinc a very strange task.
I send and receive messages[structure called message that contains the payload and the length] and I need to do byte corrections on the payload.

The structure I am using for seding and receiving messages is :

```
 typedef struct {
   int len;
   char payload[MSGSIZE];
 } msg;
```

For example i need to check the first byte of the string,because it's the parity byte[1].
I am having a hard time to figure out how to do this how can I retrieve the first byte and what type do I have to declare it

[1] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit)

Comment: If the first byte is a parity check, then it may be all zero, so it is incorrect to refer to payload as a string.  It is an array of bytes.  By any chance are you using `str...` functions?  Don't.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I fully understand what you mea but I have to stick with this structure

Comment: The first byte is `payload[0]`....I dont understand the question.  It is already declared as a char.  (IMO, it should be unsigned char)

Comment: A char holds 1 bit so to answer your question.yes,it's bit

Comment: No, a char holds 8 bits.

Comment: If you are expanding the data to be one bit per char, then you should reference it the same way.

Comment: Ok,then for setting or extracting the value of the bit is it correct to asume the variable that does this has to be of type int?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73339/discussion-between-william-pursell-and-tudoricc).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code to do what I think you want.  The key here is that myMessage.payload + n, is a char* that starts at n bytes from the beginning of paload.  The parity byte you can just accessed as payload[offset].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MSGSIZE (100)

typedef struct {
    int len;
    char payload[MSGSIZE];
} msg;



int main(){

    msg myMessage;
    // put some stuff in message for a testing
    myMessage.len = 10;
    myMessage.payload[0] = (char)17;  // parity byte just may up its value
    strcpy(myMessage.payload + 1, "1234567890"); // copy a string of ten bytes to payload after the parity byte.

    // read the message
    printf("Message has len %d\n", myMessage.len);
    printf("Message parity byte is %d\n", (int)myMessage.payload[0]);
    printf("Message is %s\n", myMessage.payload + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

output from sample

Message has len 10

Message parity byte is 17

Message is 1234567890